# Drop down Menu Data set from api

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio, dart, android-studio

I am working on e commerce application in that app I want to set dropdown data from api. I am fresher in flutter so I need to help

Dropdown Code

```
DropdownButton<String>(
                                value: _selectedOption,
                                items:_options.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                                        (String value) {
                                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                    value: value,
                                    child: Text(value),
                                  );
                                }).toList(),
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                          setState(() {
                                       _selectedOption = value!;
                                            });
                                },
 
                             ),
```

```
@override
 void initState() {
   ProductDetailsNet.fetchProductDetails(widget.utils.id.toString()).then(
           (value) {
         List<String> fetchedOptions = value.cast<String>();

         List<String> options = [];
         for (String option in fetchedOptions) {
           String concatenatedOption = option;
           options.add(concatenatedOption);         }
         setState(() {
           _options = options;
           _selectedOption = _options.isNotEmpty ? _options[0] : '';
         });
       }
   );
 }
```

my api calling code:

```
class ProductDetailsNet{
  static List<ProductDetailsUtils> parseService (String responseBody){
    var list=json.decode(responseBody) as List<dynamic>;
    List<ProductDetailsUtils> serviceList=list.map((e) => ProductDetailsUtils.fromJson(e)).toList();
    return serviceList;
  }
 static Future<List<ProductDetailsUtils>> fetchProductDetails(String pid ) async{
    final url=Uri.parse('https://wiz-mart.com/api/prodetails.php');
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String? username=prefs.getString("username");
    final queryParams = {
      'username': username,
      'pid': pid,
    };
    final newUrl = url.replace(queryParameters: queryParams);
    print(newUrl);
    try{
      final response = await http.get(newUrl);
      if (response.statusCode == 200)
      {
        final data = json.decode(response.body);
        List<String> options = [];

        String option1 = "${data['psize']} ${data['uom']}";
        String option2 = "${data['psize2']} ${data['uom2']}";
        String option3 = "${data['price3']} ${data['uom3']}";

        options.add(option1);
        options.add(option2);
        options.add(option3);
        print('Login successful!');
        print(response.body);
        return parseService(response.body);
      }else {
        print('Login failed! Status code: ${response.statusCode}');
        print('Response body: ${response.body}');

      }
    }catch (error) {
      print('Error occurred: $error');

    }
    throw Exception('Unable to retrieve product details.');



  }
```

when I run this code I got error  Error occurred: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
and my data not set to the widgets. So what should I do for.

Answer (score 0):

I've added the whole code from my own project. Think, test, and try to customize yourself.[image]

API services

```
//Division API - replaice your own model instade of DistrictModel
var divisionUrl = "$baseURL/location/division";

Future<DivisionModel?> getDivition() async {
  var res = await http.get(Uri.parse(divisionUrl));
  var divitionStatusCode = res.statusCode;
  print("Divition status code $divitionStatusCode");
  if (res.statusCode == 200) {
    DivisionModel division = divisionModelFromJson(res.body);
    return division;
  }
  return null;
}

//district API 
Future<DistrictModel?> getDistrict(String divisionId) async { 
  final uri = Uri.parse(
      '$baseURL/location/district?division_id=$divisionId');
  final response = await http.get(uri);

  var districtStatusCode = response.statusCode;
  print("District status code $districtStatusCode");
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    DistrictModel district = districtModelFromJson(response.body);
    return district;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Here is how I called and implement API response in the dropdown.

```
class RegisterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegisterPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<RegisterPage> createState() => _RegisterPageState();
}

class _RegisterPageState extends State<RegisterPage> {
  List<Divition> listOfDivition =
      []; //get all the divition from api in this list
  String? selectedDivition; //get selected divition id

  @override
  void initState() {
    loadingDivition(); //load the divition data first
    super.initState();
  }

  var isLoading = true; //to check the API is loading or not
  loadingDivition() async {
    //binding with the diviton Url
    DivisionModel? divition = await getDivition();
    setState(() {
      listOfDivition = divition!.data;
      isLoading = false; //after getting the Data loading will be false
    });
  }

  List<District> listOfDistrict =
      []; //get all the district from api in this list
  String? selectedDistrict;

  loadingDistrict() async {
    DistrictModel? district = await getDistrict(selectedDivition.toString());
    setState(() {
      listOfDistrict = district!.data;
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  GlobalKey<FormState> registerFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String? divitionValue = "";
  String? districtValue = "";

  Future<void> publicUserRegister() async {
    if (selectedDivition!.isNotEmpty && selectedDistrict!.isNotEmpty) {
      var registerData = {
        "division_id": selectedDivition,
        "district_id": selectedDistrict
      };

      var response = await registerUser(registerData);

      var body = jsonDecode(response.body);
      var responseMsg = body['message'];
      print(responseMsg);
    } else {
      print("All fields are required!");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xffffffff),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
        child: Form(
          key: registerFormKey,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              DropdownButtonFormField(
                hint: const Text(
                  "-- Select Divition --",
                ),
                value: selectedDivition,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  selectedDistrict = null;
                  setState(() {
                    selectedDivition = value;
                    loadingDistrict();
                    isLoading = true;
                  });
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    divitionValue = value;
                  });
                },
                items: listOfDivition.map((e) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: e.id.toString(),
                    child: Text(e.nameBn),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
              DropdownButtonFormField(
                hint: const Text(
                  "-- Select District --",
                ),
                value: selectedDistrict,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedDistrict = value;
                  });
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    districtValue = value;
                  });
                },
                validator: (String? value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return "can't empty";
                  } else {
                    return null;
                  }
                },
                items: listOfDistrict.map((e) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: e.id.toString(),
                    child: Text(e.nameBn),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Future Builder, It will take the stream and display data in your dropdown.

Here is the link of GitHub repo where i have used Future Builder
https://github.com/zeeshan564/News-Application/blob/API-Integration/lib/screens/home_screen/home_screen.dart

Comment: Show example code rather than link. it will be good