# Error in DropDown option "There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value:"

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

Im using this package [dropdown_button2](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2) in my flutter app.

There i have two drop down buttons. 1st one to fetch and load items for locations from an api and the 2nd one to fetch and load brands for the selection in 1st drop down.

I use the two drop down as follows

```
      Row(
          children: [
            CustomDropdownWidget<String>(
              key: Key('location_dropdown'),
              dropdownOptions: _locationStringList,
              onItemSelected: (String selectedValue) {
                // Do something with the selected value.
                print('Selected Value: $selectedValue');
                _getBrandsForLocation(selectedValue.toString());
              },
              label: 'Location',
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 8),
            AbsorbPointer(
              absorbing: !_isLocationSelected,
              child: CustomDropdownWidget<String>(
                key: Key('brand_dropdown'),
                dropdownOptions: _brandStringList,
                onItemSelected: (String selectedValue) {
                  // Do something with the selected value.
                  print('Selected Value: $selectedValue');
                  _setSelectedBrand(selectedValue.toString());
                },
                label: 'Brand',
              ),
            ),
           ],
          ),
```

And i have created the common widget as follows

```
    class CustomDropdownWidget<String> extends StatefulWidget {
     final List<String> dropdownOptions;
     final ValueChanged<String> onItemSelected;
     final String label;

    const CustomDropdownWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.dropdownOptions,
    required this.onItemSelected,
    required this.label,
    }) : super(key: key);

    @override
    _CustomDropdownWidgetState<String> createState() =>
      _CustomDropdownWidgetState<String>();
    }

    class _CustomDropdownWidgetState<String>
    extends State<CustomDropdownWidget<String>> {
    String? _selectedOption;
    String? _label;

    @override
    void initState() {
    _label = widget.label;
    super.initState();
    }

    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _addDividersAfterItems(List<String> items) {
    final List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> menuItems = [];
    for (final item in items) {
      menuItems.addAll(
        [
          DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: item,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              child: Text(
                item.toString(),
                style: tBodyMedium6,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //If it's last item, we will not add Divider after it.
          if (item != items.last)
            const DropdownMenuItem(
              enabled: false,
              child: Divider(
                color: cGreyScale1,
              ),
            ),
        ],
      );
    }
    return menuItems;
    }

    List<double> _getCustomItemsHeights() {
    final List<double> itemsHeights = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < (widget.dropdownOptions.length * 2) - 1; i++) {
      if (i.isEven) {
        itemsHeights.add(40);
      }
      //Dividers indexes will be the odd indexes
      if (i.isOdd) {
        itemsHeights.add(4);
      }
    }
    return itemsHeights;
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: cWhite,
      width: 220,
      height: 44,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: Container(
              width: 44,
              height: 44,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(5),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(5),
                ),
                border: Border.all(width: 1, color: cGreyScale1),
                color: cGreyScale0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
            child: DropdownButton2<String>(
              isExpanded: true,
              items:
                  _addDividersAfterItems(widget.dropdownOptions.cast<String>()),
              value: _selectedOption,
              hint: Text(
                '${_label}',
                style: tBodyMedium4,
              ),
              onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                if (newValue != null) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedOption = newValue;
                  });
                  widget.onItemSelected(newValue);
                }
              },
              buttonStyleData: ButtonStyleData(
                width: 220,
                height: 44,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  border: Border.all(width: 1, color: cGreyScale1),
                ),
              ),
              iconStyleData: const IconStyleData(
                icon: Icon(IconlyLight.arrow_down_2),
                iconSize: 24,
                iconEnabledColor: cGreyScale3,
                iconDisabledColor: cGreyScale3,
              ),
              dropdownStyleData: DropdownStyleData(
                width: 220,
                elevation: 4,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  color: cWhite,
                ),
                offset: const Offset(0, -5),
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              ),
              menuItemStyleData: MenuItemStyleData(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                customHeights: _getCustomItemsHeights(),
                // _options.isNotEmpty ? _getCustomItemsHeights() : [],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
     );
     }
     }
```

This is the snippet for fetching and loading items for each drop down list.

```
*void _getLocations() async {
BotToast.showLoading(
  backButtonBehavior: BackButtonBehavior.none,
);
_locationList = await _repository!.getLocationsByPartnerID();
List<String> itemList = [];
_locationList.forEach((e) {
  itemList.add(e.name!);
});
setState(() {
  _locationStringList = itemList;
});
BotToast.closeAllLoading();
}

void _getBrandsForLocation(String location) async {
BotToast.showLoading(
  backButtonBehavior: BackButtonBehavior.none,
);
_setSelectedLocation(location);

if (_brandStringList.isNotEmpty) {
  setState(() {
    _brandStringList = [];
    _selectedBrand = null;
    _isLocationSelected = false;
  });
}
_brandList = await _repository!.getBrandsByID(_selectedLocation!);
List<String> itemList = [];
_brandList.forEach((e) {
  itemList.add(e.name!.text!);
});

setState(() {
  _brandStringList = itemList;
  _isLocationSelected = true;
});
BotToast.closeAllLoading();
}*
```

For the first time i fetch the locations and choose a location the brands drop down loads with items and shows the options. And i can select a brand with no issue. The second instance i choose another location it does fetch the brands from the api but right after done fetching i receive the following error.

*"There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: "'$value. \n''Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected ''with the same value',*

And no matter what i do i cant seems to fix this behavior. So i need help in solving this and i highly appreciate the input. Was wasting time for this issue.

Comment: Well, are there two brands with the same name?

Comment: I did solve this kind of problem with DropdownButtonFormField (based on multiple api). Here you can see my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76936440/12965265

Comment: @TimRoberts no there are no brands with the same name though